# Is every Lindelöf quasi-metrizable space separable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

A Hausdorff space $(X,\tau)$ is *quasi-metrizable* iff there is a function $g: \omega \times X \to \tau$ such that

(i) $\{g(n,x): n\in \omega\}$ is a local base at $x$;

(ii) $y\in g(n+1, x) \implies g(n+1, y) \subset g(n,x)$.

As we know, every Lindelöf metrizable space is separable. But,

> Is every Lindelöf quasi-metrizable space separable?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried the same proof idea? So cover $X$ by $g(n,x), x \in X$ and taking countable subcovers and collecting the $x$ used in those, for all $n$? What goes wrong there?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Yes, I've tried, but it seems difficult to go on.