# Do we have $e(G)=l(G)$ always for any first countable paratopological group.?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cardinals, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a (Hausdorff, regular, Tychonoff) first countable paratopological group.

> Do we have $e(G)=l(G)$ always? (Clearly, $e(G) \le l(G)$.)

Definitions:

1. The Lindelof number $l(X)$ of a topological space $X$ is the
   smallest number $\kappa$ such that every open cover of $X$ has a
   subcover the cardinality of which is at most $\kappa$.
2. The extent $e(X)$ of $X$ is the supremum of the cardinalities of
   closed discrete subsets of $X$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is a paratopological group?

Comment: Does it hold for standard topological groups?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Yes, since every first countable topological group is metrizable.

Comment: It is known that every first countable paratopological group is quasi-metrizable. see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304135/is-every-lindel%c3%b6f-quasi-metrizable-space-separable